# Joining a table where reference exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5.3

I'm looking to create a join using Laravel where it selects a whole table if the join references do not exist but otherwise joins the other tables.

```
DB::table('tInfo')
->join('tStaff', 'tStaff.tourID', '=', 'tInfo.tcode')->get()
```

`tInfo` is a 'one to many' relationship with `tStaff` and `tStaff` will have rows linked to a specific tour

I removed the 'tStaff' reference and noticed the query does not return a row (no errors included). I assume this is because the join is invalid.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share your `tInfo`, `tStaff` and `sInfo` table structure. Otherwise it is hard to tell either you have a foreign key reference in `sInfo` table or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
  DB::table('tInfo as inf')
              ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('tourID'))
                  ->from('tStaff')
                  ->whereRaw('inf.tcode= tStaff.tourID');
        })
        ->get();
```